# One-time binding syntax

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and was not sure if this is the recommended syntax in Angular. In AngularJS, we can do one-time binding in this way:

```html
<p>{{::myVar}}</p>
```

In Angular, I know we can do this.

```html
<p [innerText]="myVar"></p>
```

My first question is, is this the only way to achieve `{{::}}` in Angular?

What if I have this situation in AngularJS:

```html
<p>{{::myVar}} is a variable</p>
```

I have tried something like this

```html
<p [innerText]="myVar + 'is a variable'"></p>
```

It works but again is this the recommended syntax?

Comment: Have your tried `<p>{{myVar}}</p>` ?

Comment: yes, I know it works but I don't want to do two-way binding.

Comment: In AngularJS, `{{::myVar}}` is not just one-way, it is one-time.

Comment: `<p>{{myVar}}</p>` is not 2 way binding. It's one way binding.

Comment: Then you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375624/angular-2-one-time-binding

Comment: @CharlieNg I think my answer is irrelevant now after you updated your question. one time binding is different than one way binding! I will update my answer any way.

Answer (score 1):

in angular there are three ways of one way data biding from the component to the template:

- Interpolation `{{myVar}`}  => recommended use case: `<p>{{myVar}} is a variable</p>`
- Property binding `[attri]="url"` =>  `<img [src]="url">`
- `bind-target="myVar"`

**EDIT:** one time binding on the other hand is a feature we used to have in angular 1 and you can replicate it in angular using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.CheckOnce`

check the official docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html)