# what about the performance of one-time-binding and read-only

Tags: angularjs, readonly, one-time-binding

### One-time data binding:

As its name suggests, the binding happens only once, ie, in the first digest cycle. One-time binding allows for a model or view to be updated ONCE from the value set by the controller upon the first digest

The syntax is `{{::expression}}.` in angularjs and in angular 2 is here :[angular 2 one time binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375624/angular-2-one-time-binding)

### Read-only

Sets the readonly attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngReadonly is truthy. Note that readonly applies only to input elements with specific types

The syntax is  `ng-readonly="expression"` and angular 2 have `[readonly]="true"`

### Difference and Question

I guess both are similarly doing the same process but the only difference is `read-only` is allow to disable the control. ***So what about the performance between those and their have any other difference***?

Comment: `[readonly]="true"` does not prevent the value from being bound again from the model. It only prevents user input

Comment: But we can set the value as dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering for the angularjs part :

**ng-readonly** does not affect performance it only set the readonly attribute of your input.
Perhaps you want to combine them if your readonly expression does not change after your directive/controller first load :

```
ng-readonly="::expression"
```

With this you prevent angularjs to watch your expression so it's a performance gain.