# How to keep values in disabled input control when model changes?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I have a JSON object using which I create a form having one disabled control and one enabled input control for each value, Disabled inputs are for reference for user while he may change values in active Input control. I need to keep values fixed in disabled Input, while using the same model. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: It's a template driven form or a reactive form?

Comment: provide a short example on plunk or stackblitz plz... so that others can help you easily.

Comment: its a template driven form.

Comment: You may find something useful here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375624/angular-2-one-time-binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using template driven forms, you can use one-time binding on the disabled elements so they won't update.

This will be even easier with reactive forms as the form model and data model are already separate.

Here is an example (template driven forms):

Normally bound (editable) item:

```
      <input class="form-control"
             id="productNameId"
             type="text"
             placeholder="Name (required)"
             required
             minlength="3"
             [(ngModel)]=product.productName
             name="productName" />
```

One-time binding (non-editable) item:

```
      <input class="form-control"
             id="productNameId"
             type="text"
             placeholder="Name (required)"
             required
             minlength="3"
             ngModel=product.productName   /* <- the difference is here */
             name="productName" />
```

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnyy5d

`[(ngModel)]` -> two-way binding

`[ngModel]` -> one-way binding

`ngModel` -> one-time binding (only binds the initial value and won't update)

Comment: They will update, if you are changing values in the enabled inputs and enabled inputs  have two way binding (provided both are using the same variable)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should not try to answer questions at 1:30 AM! I meant "one-time" binding. Fixed in my answer.

Comment: Yes if model changed they will change.

Comment: Can you confirm with my stackblitz?

Comment: Did you look at my stackblitz? It demonstrates the technique and is working.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working on my code now . Did not know of such ability of ngModel. Thanks again.